# wpf/silverlight mvvm sample app request

Tags: wpf, silverlight, mvvm, sample

could you guys point me to some really simple silverlight or wpf sample project where the usage of the MVVM is showed

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Josh Smiths](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) article and app in MVVM WPF, or have a a look at [Sacha Barber's](http://sachabarber.net/) application Cinch V.2, again, a really good app with brilliant explanations. I reckon start with Josh smiths and then on to Cinch.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.vertigo.com/familyshow.aspx

Comment: it's a cool app, but it's not that simple, and I don't understand where is the usage of mvvm

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: These are some MVVM examples I have built...

Here is a [Twitter search app example](http://houseofbilz.com/archives/2009/06/19/adventures-in-mvvm-ball-of-mud-vs-mvvm/) showing the same ball-of-mud in comparison to MVVM.
Here is a slightly more complex [conference schedule app](http://houseofbilz.com/archives/2010/01/11/adventures-in-mvvm-codemash-schedule-application/) showing MVVM pretty heavily.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in the sample applications of the **[WPF Application Framework (WAF)](http://waf.codeplex.com)**. They show:

- View composition
- UI Workflow (Wizards)
- Command binding / Shortcut Keys
- MVVM pattern, Unit Testing
- Validation
- Entity Framework
- Open/Save FileDialog
- Print Preview / Print Dialog
- Localization