# Looking for simple MVVM Light example

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I'm trying to learn MVVM Light and am looking for a good basic example that shows a model and how to load different views.

The template I see after downloading MVVM Light has no models and only one view.  (http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/creating/)

Other things I've found are more complex and a bit confusing when all I want to see are the basics.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have found this example helpful:

http://apuntanotas.codeplex.com/

Comment: The "model" in this example implements INotify. I tend to think of the Model as using POCOs (Plain Old CLR Object) and with the ModelView implementing the INotify to allow data binding.

Comment: This answer is no longer helpful to man or beast because the link includes no code or any useful information whatsoever

Comment: As of July 2020, there's a big "download archive" link at the top of the page - click there, go to sourceCode/sourceCode.zip. You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I have personally found these to be quite useful, though they also use MEF and RIA Services which can complicate things:

[A Sample Silverlight 4 Application Using MEF, MVVM, and WCF RIA Services](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/IssueVisionForSilverlight.aspx)

[Architecting Silverlight 4 with RIA Services MEF and MVVM - Part 1](http://wildermuth.com/2009/12/15/Architecting_Silverlight_4_with_RIA_Services_MEF_and_MVVM_-_Part_1)

In April, the author of the MVVM Light toolkit said that he would eventually be creating a reference application in both Silverlight and WPF. [(Source)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687172/mvvm-light-toolkit-samples/2697545#2697545)

You might find these other questions useful:

[mvvm light toolkit samples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687172/mvvm-light-toolkit-samples)

[wpf/silverlight mvvm sample app request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278726/wpf-silverlight-mvvm-sample-app-request)

[mvvm tutorial from start to finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405739/mvvm-tutorial-from-start-to-finish)

Answer (score 1):

I found these two to be very helpful:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/blendable_locator.aspx
[http://rickrat.wordpress.com/2011/01/24/using-mef-to-link-view-model-locator-and-load-assembly-uis-dynamically](http://rickrat.wordpress.com/2011/01/24/using-mef-to-link-view-model-locator-and-load-assembly-uis-dynamically/)

The [first](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/blendable_locator.aspx) one is just a simple drop-in viewModelLocator class for MVVM Light that gives you the MEF abilities.

```
[ExportViewModel("Demo1", false)]
class Demo1ViewModel : ViewModel
{   
}
```

And the [second](http://rickrat.wordpress.com/2011/01/24/using-mef-to-link-view-model-locator-and-load-assembly-uis-dynamically/) one, uses the same approach with an additional MefHelper class that enables run time loading of MEF components.

```
public void Compose()
{
AggregateCatalog Catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
// Add This assembly's catalog parts
System.Reflection.Assembly ass = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
Catalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(ass));

// Directory of catalog parts
if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(ExtensionsPath))
{
    Catalog.Catalogs.Add(new DirectoryCatalog(ExtensionsPath));
    string[] folders = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(ExtensionsPath);

    foreach (string folder in folders)
    {
        Catalog.Catalogs.Add(new DirectoryCatalog(folder));
    }

}

_Container = new CompositionContainer(Catalog);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the following tutorials to be a quick and easy way to get started:

[MVVM Light Toolkit Example](http://dotnetpattern.com/mvvm-light-toolkit-example)

[MVVM Step By Step](http://www.ijohnsen.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/MvvmControlChange-StepbyStep-v1.pdf)