# mvvm mapping model to data

Tags: wpf, mvvm, entity-framework-4.1, mapping

While developing a wpf application using `mvvm`, my boss tells me to find a way to map data from model classes to object.

Is there anything as such or am I getting it wrong, and I tried using the "entity framework" to do the job.

But it doesn't meet his requirements, you can assume that i am particularly new to mvvm as such and is there any helpful solution I can look into?

Comment: Have a look  here http://galasoft.ch/mvvm/

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx

Comment: Perhaps you have to investigate some links here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848375/looking-for-simple-mvvm-light-example

Comment: @subst13 he will come to framework anyway

Comment: @DmitryBoyko - Maybe.  He should start without a framework to understand MVVM, otherwise he learns the framework and not MVVM.

Comment: @subt13. The problem is that "my boss tells" ... :)  He don't have any time to learn MVVM and find "any helpful solution" as he said. So my suggestions are good I am sure.

Comment: @DmitryBoyko - Haha, fair enough.  In my case I got basic MVVM up and running in short order without any need to learn a framework first.  You don't understand WHY you need a framework until you do it the normal way a few times.

Comment: @subt13 Let's have a beer and leave our new college ADIAGYA with his boss and MVVM! Hahahahaa

Answer (score 1):

I wonder does the problem you talking about is related to MVVM.

If you only mean your model class is some sort of data object that is returned from database and you would like to maps to another data object, you can try using [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20Started).  It maps object to objects.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest to you the following:

1) One of the good MVVM toolkit is here http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/

2) Some useful links you can find here    [Looking for simple MVVM Light example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848375/looking-for-simple-mvvm-light-example)

Comment: That's better (though i could not comment on `good` either since i did not use it yet)